# How should I version control sagemaker model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, deployment, amazon-sagemaker, concourse

So I have a pre-trained ML model stored in an S3 bucket (name`example.tar.gz`), I have a pipeline, and it will run terraform to create a model by using this file on SageMaker and get prediction, my question is what's the best practice of version control the created-model on SageMaker?

My thought is I manually set this model artifact a name like `example-v1.tar.gz`, meaning this is the first artifact we will deploy, then because my pipeline can version control the terraform code (build a `terraform-v1.0.0.zip` file) then execute this file to create the model on SageMaker, my question is basically should I just use `model-v1` as model name on SageMaker or should I update this model name frequently, like everytime there's a new-versioned terraform zip file, we use the same version number for the model name on SageMaker (`model-v1.0.0`)?

I'm new to ML model deployment, a bit confused about this, hope this makes sense, can someone help me?Thanks.

Comment: https://dvc.org/

Comment: @Cecilia: Is your question is resolved?

Comment: hmm not really...

Comment: Lots of things combined together that don't relate to each other. Terraform and Sagemaker should not be "close" to each other since they solve different needs. Models are registered in Sagemaker model registry. Each model group can have many models. Each model can have many versions. Read Sagemaker docs to remove confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sagemaker Model Registry to register your model and version control: [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry-version.html)

Usage example:

```
# Specify the model source
model_url = "s3://your-bucket-name/model.tar.gz"

modelpackage_inference_specification =  {
    "InferenceSpecification": {
      "Containers": [
         {
            "Image": '257758044811.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-xgboost:1.2-1',
        "ModelDataUrl": model_url
         }
      ],
      "SupportedContentTypes": [ "text/csv" ],
      "SupportedResponseMIMETypes": [ "text/csv" ],
   }
 }

# Alternatively, you can specify the model source like this:
# modelpackage_inference_specification["InferenceSpecification"]["Containers"][0]["ModelDataUrl"]=model_url

create_model_package_input_dict = {
    "ModelPackageGroupName" : model_package_group_name,
    "ModelPackageDescription" : "Model to detect 3 different types of irises (Setosa, Versicolour, and Virginica)",
    "ModelApprovalStatus" : "PendingManualApproval"
}
create_model_package_input_dict.update(modelpackage_inference_specification)
```